# How to Send Email with predefined Template in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, email, email-template, salesforce-classic

In Lightning, how does one create a quick way for users to send an email with specific email template pre-selected? In classic, we can use URL parameters and do the same but with lightning that's not even an option.

This is a template they will be sending over and over again.  I would like for this to be a Quick Action or Custom Button but have run into issues.

PS: This one is not for Case, as for Case there's an option available.

Possible Solutions I can think of is:

1. Build a Lightning Component which will call/open the classic email
   composer with pre-populated data within Lightning UI. This actually works, but dont like this idea of using classic while in Lightning and may be it will stop working the day classic goes off or is turned off.
2. Build custom VF page (or lightning component) with lightning look &
   feel with COMPOSE functionality with the pre-populated body, subject, to
   and cc.